# Send mail with ma

Tags: flutter, dart

This code returns "Message not sent" in run and not send message to email.

I want to send auto mail to gmail with sendMail function.

I copied this code from dard pub and github.

```
sendMail() async {
      String username = '*******@gmail.com';
      String password = '*********';
      final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
    
      final message = Message()
        ..from = Address(username)
        ..recipients.add('********@gmail.com')
        ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${DateTime.now()}'
        ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
        ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>Hey! Here's some HTML content</p>";
    
      try {
        final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
        print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
      } on MailerException catch (e) {
        print('Message not sent.');
        for (var p in e.problems) {
          print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message wont be sent, because you are using your normal Gmail password. Just need to generate an app password. An app password is a 16-digit passcode that gives a non-Google app or device permission to access your Google Account.

Follow these steps for [signing in using app passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB#:%7E:text=Why%20you%20may%20need%20an,device%20access%20your%20Google%20Account.). Hope this hepls!